# How to block initiator from accessing others task in Alfresco BPM?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

Right now, workflow's initiator can access, edit and approve all tasks within the process. **Is there a way to block this?**

I do not want a situation where an employee asks for a pay rise and gives it to himself. (just an example)

Comment: But the pay rise details appears in the workflow details / history page ?

Comment: Well, it was just an example. But no, none of my custom process variables is shown in the history page

Comment: are you using activiti embedded in alfresco?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala I am using Alfresco 6.1.2 Community Edition so I suppose there is an embedded Activiti enginee, version 5.22

Comment: not sure about the embedded one, but the licensed version of activiti (APS) holds an attribute on task for restricting initiators to complete